# How to add a placeholder (spinner) while loading Telegram mini app?

Tags: reactjs, telegram-bot, placeholder

I'm making the Front part of an application in React and can't find information on how to implement the application's loading behavior. I take 2 bots as an example (Wallet, Durger King), they have their own placeholders. I can only implement a white screen (screen from a third-party bot "@Nespat_bot").

[durger-king_bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2xCk.jpg) - image (good)

[nespat_bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd6hI.jpg) - image (bad)

I tried adding  inside index.js, but it was rendered after the application was initialized.
It seems to me that this placeholder needs to be added somewhere outside the react application, but I don’t know where

Comment: At the moment, you can't do that. As far as I know, Durger King has its own loader built in the Telegram application, that's why you see it. All we can see now is only the white screen

Answer (score 0):

Did you try lazy loading with Suspense components?

Comment: yes, it doesn't help. The problem is that apparently there is no method that allows you to implement this, and in applications (Wallet, Durger King) I did not find the source code to look at

Comment: This is not an answer, but seems like a question for clarification that should go under "add a comment".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).